# Is this linear independence proof valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let's say we have a 4x4 nilpotent matrix $V$ with an index of 4 and a vector $\vec{x}$ which is an element of $\mathcal{R}^4$, matrix $V$ and $\vec{x}$ are non-zero. How would we show that $V\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}$ are linearly independent? The following is what I did but I personally think that my answer is somewhat iffy.

$$
\lambda_1\vec{x} + \lambda_2V\vec{x} = \vec{0}
\\
\lambda_1(\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2}+\vec{x_3}+\vec{x_4)} + \lambda_2V(\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2}+\vec{x_3}+\vec{x_4}) = \vec{0}
$$
Factorizing it according to the vectors $\vec{x_1}$ to $\vec{x_4}$:
$$
(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2V)\vec{x_1}+(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2V)\vec{x_2}+(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2V)\vec{x_3}+(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2V)\vec{x_4} = \vec{0}
$$
Solving this would give, all coefficients as 0 since they're all the same. I think I messed up somewhere in my understanding of linear independence or something but please help and explain it to me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are $\ x_1, x_2, x_3\ $ and $\ x_4\ $?

Comment: I just expressed $\vec{x}$ as a linear combination of $\vec{x_1},\vec{x_2},\vec{x_3}$ and$\vec{x_4}$

Comment: But what *are* they?  Since $\ \vec{x}\ne0\ $, you can always find a some of linearly independent vectors $\ \vec{x_1}\ $, $\ \vec{x_2}\ $, $\ \vec{x_3}\ $, $\ \vec{x_4}\ $,  such that $\ \vec{x}=$$\vec{x_1}+$$\vec{x_2}+$$\vec{x_3}+$$\vec{x_4}\ $, but if that's all you've done you have no justification for concluding that $\ \lambda_1\ $ and $\ \lambda_2\ $ are zero from the last equation you wrote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given, the statement you're asking to be proved is not necessarily true, because $\ V\vec{x}\ $ could be zero, even if both $\ V\ $ and $\ \vec{x}\ $ are non-zero, and if $\ V\vec{x}=\vec{0}\ $, then $\ V\vec{x}\ $ and $\ \vec{x}\ $ are not linearly independent.

Since $\ V\ $ is nilpotent, then there must be a smallest power, $\ V^n\ $, of $\ V\ $ that annihilates $\ \vec{x}\ $ (that is, $\ V^n\vec{x}=\vec{0}\ $  and $\ V^{n-1}\vec{x}\ne\vec{0}\ $), and  if $\ V\vec{x}\ne\vec{0}\ $, then $\ n\ge2\ $. Suppose, in this case, that
$$
\lambda_1 \vec{x}+ \lambda_2 V\vec{x}= \vec{0}\ .
$$
Multiplying this equation by $\ V^{n-1}\ $ gives
$$
\vec{0}=\lambda_1 V^{n-1} \vec{x}+ \lambda_2 V^n\vec{x}= \lambda_1 V^{n-1} \vec{x}\ .
$$
Since $\ V^{n-1}\vec{x}\ne\vec{0}\ $, it follow that $\  \lambda_1=0\ $ and then that $\ \lambda_2 V\vec{x}= \vec{0}\ $. Since $\ V\vec{x}\ne\vec{0}\ $ it also follows that $\ \lambda_2=0\ $. Thus if $\  V\vec{x} \ne\vec{0}\ $ then $\ \vec{x}\ $ and $\ V\vec{x}\ $  are linearly independent.